# How do I make an object spawn randomly in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a space game in unity It's going great but I can't spawn my objects in a radius I tried using the mathematical equation log but it didn't work and it spoiled my rocketship movement.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class deployAsteroids : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject asteroidPrefab;
    public float Time = 1.0f;
    private Vector2 screenBounds;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        StartCoroutine(asteroidWave());
    }

    private void spawnAsteroid()
    {
        GameObject a = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab) as GameObject;
        a.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
    }

    IEnumerator asteroidWave()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time);
            spawnAsteroid();
        }
    }
}
```

The code also removes an asteroid once It's of your screen.
Hope It's not too much to ask.

Comment: Can you specify that don't work? The asteroid don't spawn? The asteroid spawn at unexpected position? What mean "spoiled my rocketship movement"?

Comment: `I can't spawn my objects in a radius` what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: `The code also removes an asteroid once It's of your screen` .. no it doesn't ... this seems to be another question ?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [`Random.insideUnitCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html) ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to spawn asteroids within a big circle where your rocketship is in the exact center of that circle? If so, you can try to solve for its x and y position using a unit circle:

```
float x = radius * cos(Random.Range(0, 2(Math.PI)));
float y = radius * sin(Random.Range(0, 2(Math.PI)));
```

Something like that will randomly spawn them on the edges of your circle. Look at the trigonometry part of this picture I found:

[image]

From this picture, you want x and y, you know radius r, and you can randomly generate theta by using Random.Range()

If you wanted to spawn them randomly within ANYWHERE in the circle, also randomize the radius, making the maximum range radius like

```
float x = Random.Range(0, radius) * cos(Random.Range(0, 2(Math.PI)));
```

User derHugo suggested a helper function in Unity that does this math for you already. You can try directly setting the transform position doing:

```
a.transform.position = Random.insideUnitCircle * radius;
```

Comment: And why would you use `double` when everything in Unity is `float`? ^^ ... also there is [`Random.insideUnitCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html) which already does all that for you ...

Comment: I know C# primarily and not too much Unity. I can add this at the end to simplify it for the poster

Comment: It worked perfectly but there is one problem unity uses float not double. Still thanks!

Comment: No problem. If this helps you, could you accept my answer?

Comment: `Random.insideUnitCircle * Random.Range(0, radius);` is quite redundant ... **inside** laready suggests that the value is somewhere inside a circle ;)